# ggplot multiple line plot y-axis so weird in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a dataframe long format, and this is the code for ggplot.
[Please see the code here, I have no idea why it does not show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mduC5.png)

I was expecting things like this:
[image]

However I got this:

[image]

You can see how strange the y-axis is. Can somebody help me please? Thank you in advance!

I tried ggplot, however the y-axis is not correct at all.

Comment: Is your y-variable a character or factor? Try converting it to numeric.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: `df_new_long$value <- as.numeric(df_new_long$value)` is the code the teunbrand suggested. Run that the rerun your `ggplot(..)` expression. If you go to this state, it suggests one or more of: (1) including too many columns (e.g., one or more non-`numeric` columns) when you `melt`ed, causing the `value` column to be non-numeric; (2) import of the data was incorrect, a column that should be numeric is not; (3) something else we can't know. Improve your question by including _real_ code (not images) plus an unambiguous sample of your data, perhaps `dput(head(df_new,20))`.